# Chai expect to throw with error message

Tags: javascript, chai

I'm trying to test the message of an `Error` using `expect().to.throw`.  I read that expect needs to be passed a function to execute, as oppose to the function that returns.  Anyways, I still can't seem to get this to work, I've tried a number of variations, but this is the basic setup in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2qm7uge/1/).  Any ideas why this won't work or how can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Ok I'm an idiot.  I'm not throwing anything, just returning new Error.  It works if I use `throw new Error()`

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I was using `throw` to check, but I wasn't actually throwing an error, but returning an `Error`.  The following evaluates correctly:

```
expect(test.throwFunction()).to.be.an.instanceOf(Error).with.property('message', 'This is an error message')
```

However, I'm not sure this is the cleanest way to check - seems like there could be a shorthand version.

Update: Looks like there's a [work in progress](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/pull/1021) for adding `to.be.an.error`